ROS2 cancel action_server goal in javascript
can someone help me regrading how to cancel the action server goal?
This is my current code:
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var fibonacciClient = new ROSLIB.Action({
         ros : ros,
         name : '/fibonacci',
         actionType : 'action_tutorials_interfaces/Fibonacci'
    });

    // Send an action goal
    var goal = new ROSLIB.ActionGoal({
        order: 10,
    });

    // Variable to store the goal ID
    var actionGoalId ;

    document.getElementById('sendGoalButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Send an action goal

    actionGoalId = fibonacciClient.sendGoal(goal,
       function(result) {
           console.log('Result for action goal on ' + fibonacciClient.name + ': ' + 
           result.result.sequence);
       },
       function(feedback) {
           console.log('Feedback for action on ' + fibonacciClient.name + ': ' + 
           feedback.partial_sequence);
       } 
       ); 
    });

    document.getElementById('cancelGoalButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Check if a goal has been sent previously
    if (actionGoalId) {
     // Send a cancel request for the previously sent goal
     fibonacciClient.cancelGoal(actionGoalId);
     console.log('Cancel request sent for goal: ' + actionGoalId);
     goal_id = null; // Reset goal_id after cancellation
    } else {
    console.log('No goal has been sent yet.');
    }   
    });
    });


Hai, the solution for this question is simply setting the send_action_goals_in_new_thread parameter on rosbridge to true.
